# Build a menu which changes based on url path and params

Tags: angularjs

Is there a good tutorial on how to create a menu in angularjs, the menu should only appear on few pages, for example:

```
localhost/web (is the page which shows all my projects)
 because I don't have any project selected I don't get a sidemenu

localhost/web/1 (is the main page of a project)
  because I've selected project 1 I can see a sidemenu.
```

My links in the sidemenu will have the projectID

```
Project Settings(url) -> localhost/web/1/settings
web.settings({projectID: projectID})
```

And many others, the sidemenu will show in all that pages where a project id is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your menu data in JSON like

// here key in json object is your current url.

```
   $scope.menus = {
                     "syllabus":[{name:"Chapters",url:"",class:"fa fa-folder-open"},{name:"Q&A",url:"url",class:"fa fa-folder-open"},{name:"syllabus 3",url:"url 1",class:"fa fa-folder-open"}],
                    };


$scope.sub_menus = [];
    $scope.setSubMenu =function(menu){
         $scope.sub_menus = $scope.menus[menu];
    }
```

Call setSubMenu function whenever you change the route. pass your current route as an argument that will set the current page menu data in to sub_menus array. angular will render this automatically for you.

```
app.directive('subMenu', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div ng-if="sub_menus.length" class="subtabs"> <ul class="nav"><li ng-repeat = "sb in sub_menus"><a href="#" ui-sref="{{sb.url}}"><i class=\"{{sb.class}}\""></i> &nbsp;{{sb.name}}</a></li>' +
            '</ul></div>',
        compile: function() {
            return {
                post: function($scope) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```